# How to place database results in ScrollBox

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to place my database results into a ScrollBox but im having a difficult time,
I was checking online and it was saying that i need to use the `scrollbox:auto` function.

But i tried add it too the CSS regarding the table for which the database results go in
but it did not work and just displayed the results all on the page.

Any guidance would be appreciated

CSS

```
.results
{
    bottom: -10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 90px;
    scrollbox: auto;    
}
```

Database Results

```
echo "<table class='results' border='1'>";


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{       
    echo "<tr >";
    echo "<td>"  . '<img style=height:45px; width:45px src="' . $row['Image'] . '"/>' . "</td>";
    echo "<td>"  . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .  "£" . $row['Cost'] . "<br>" .  '<a href='.$row['Link'].'>' . '</a>' . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: You could try to wrap the table to a div and set the scrollbox: auto; property in that div.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/nyCKE/2634/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `overflow: auto;` Or `overflow:scroll` instead of `scrollbox: auto;` 
make sure to give the scrolling-div a fixed height.